# Getting HQL instead of criteria

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have an criteria as shown below in which I pass id in the method parameter as shown below

```
public List<abcObject> getabcObjects(String id) {
    Criteria query = session.createCriteria(abcObject.class);

    if(id!=null) {
        query.add(Restrictions.eq("ID", id));
    }

    List<abcObject> abcObjectsList = query.list();

    return abcObjectsList;
}
```

As shown below ID column is being fetched from backend , could you please let me know the equilvalent HQL, for this as I was looking to wrtite HQL for to obtain the same result

Comment: Seriously. Why don't you read the documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing

Answer (score 1):

The HQL statement would be as follows:

```
select abc from abcObject abc where abc.id = :id
```

And its utilization:

```
Integer id = 0; //this will change
String hql = "select abc from abcObject abc where abc.id = :id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id", id);
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: ID will be at right hand side

Comment: ID coming from table one

Comment: please advise how to srote it contents into list as in case of crieteria